# presentModalViewController gives error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

if i run following gives error,current controller is table controller....

```
SetController  *aSecondView = [[SetController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Sets" bundle:nil];
SchedAppDelegate *mainDelegate = (SchedAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [mainDelegate setSettingsViewController:aSecondView];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:[[self view] superview] cache:YES];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self presentModalViewController:aSecondView animated:NO];
    //[aSecondView release];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears that `mView` is a `UIViewController` and not a `UIView`.

This is the proper way to apply a custom animation to a modal view controller:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:[self view] cache:YES];
[self presentModalViewController:mView animated:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: did you run it,i checked ,it did not work for UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight

Comment: have you tried forView:[[self view] superview] instead? Also, I don't have your code, so there's no way I'd be able to test it

Comment: i tried it. but i could not do it.i have edited with my complete code
can u see and answer?

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work for me either. For one thing, if there's a navigation bar then using [self view] for the animation view isn't going to work.

Answer (score 3):

If mView is a view controller, you can present it with a flip animation by doing the following:

```
mView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:mView animated:YES];
```

The modalTransitionStyle property is only available for iPhone OS 3.0 onwards. Hope this helps. :)